# Installing “data-atom@0.29.0” failed

Tags: atom-editor

I recently installed the Data Atom package in Atom on my Windows 10 work machine, but then when I came home to install it on my home machine, it just won't install! I can't figure out why it will install just fine on one Windows 10 machine, but won't install no matter what I do on the other. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Atom, upgrading Atom, upgrading npm, deleting all temp files in the .atom folder, and even tried to install it via Administrator command line with the command apm install data-atom.

Can anyone tell from the error message what the problem is?

Here is the message I get in Atom when I try to install it via Settings --> Packages --> Install:

```
Installing “data-atom@0.29.0” failed.Hide output…
C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r
`-- (empty)


npm WARN deprecated sprintf@0.1.5: The sprintf package is deprecated in favor of sprintf-js.
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.9.0: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.25.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.25.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "C:\\Users\\Chris\\.atom\\.apm\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\Chris\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d-11832-8616-2q25ts.qzvn0tqpvi\\package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=1.7.11" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\node_modules\.staging\asap-8119c2f8
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\node_modules\.staging\asap-8119c2f8' -> 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\node_modules\data-atom\node_modules\asap'
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.25.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.25.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\node_modules\.staging\asap-8119c2f8' -> 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\node_modules\data-atom\node_modules\asap'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\node_modules\.staging\asap-8119c2f8' -> 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\node_modules\data-atom\node_modules\asap'
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.25.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:25:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.25.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:264:29
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\node_modules\.staging\asap-8119c2f8' -> 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\node_modules\data-atom\node_modules\asap'
npm ERR!     at Error (native) parent: 'data-atom' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11832-8616-1h1pdcc.hxaafko6r\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: Did you rename those folders, as suggested in the error message?

Comment: I didn't realize that the message was suggesting that I rename something. I will try that. Update: Those folder paths don't exist, so there is nothing to rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to install the data-atom package in Atom when I disabled all of Malwarebytes real-time virus and malware protections.